# Confusing thread behaviour

Tags: c#

In C#, if I execute

```
for (int i = 0;i < 10;i++)
    new Thread(() => Console.Write(i)).Start();
```

I will possibly get 0223557799, that's strange, since i is a int, I think it should be copied before the thread starts.

Comment: See Eric Lippert's [Closing over the loop variable considered harmful](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx). It talks mostly about `foreach` but the same situation exists for `for` and (per the note at the top), `foreach` has been changed but `for` will not be (probably)

Comment: And "I think it should be copied before the thread starts." what or who do you think is performing a copy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Closures** are your problem here.

Basically, instead of grabbing the value when you **create** the lambda (in the loop), it grabs it when it needs it. And computers are so fast that by the time that happens, it's already changed. It can't go through the whole loop, but it goes through some of it.

Here's a fix:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
    var n = i;
    new Thread(() => Console.Write(n)).Start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `Start()` returns immediately, `i++` happens before the thread gets a chance to print `i` to the console. I believe that a workaround is to create a local copy of the int, then print that:

```
for (int i = 0;i < 10;i++) {
    int j = i;
    new Thread(() => Console.Write(j)).Start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What basically is happening is this:

1. You want to start a thread that prints the value of `i`.
2. The thread starts.
3. The code operating in the thread gets the value if `i`. **Note that the value of i can be changed by now.**
4. The value of `i` gets printed. But no guarantees to get a logical output.

Copy the value of i into another variable first and then print that value. The other answers provide enough samplecode.

Answer (score 0):

Your lambda will be translated into set of the method and context class which will handle a refference to the i.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the built in .NET parallelism support [Task Parallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx)

You won't have to worry about managing the threads it's done for you.

Example your code converted to the Parallelism libraries.

```
Parallel.For(0, 10, (i, state) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
});
```